# How to redirect output to stdout and a file with subprocess.call?

Tags: python

I call below subprocess in my Python file.

```
for Testscript in ListofTesttoRun:
    subprocess.call(["python",Testscript], stdout=self.destfileoutput)
```

Currently the output gets printed out to a result text file. What I would like to know if using `subprocess.call` how can I print to a file as well as screen.

Comment: Just write to a pipe, and manually send what you read from the pipe to both the file and your own stdout.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `subprocess.PIPE` and write its contents to both file objects.

```
import subprocess
import sys

process = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-la'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in process.stdout:
        line = line.decode('utf-8')
        outfile.write(line)
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Comment: Pipe works I have checked that. Does this mean that I cant achieve the same using  "Subprocess.Call " ?

Comment: @smi `subprocess.Popen` and `subprocess.call` has same input arguments API, if that's what you ask for.

Comment: See the documentation of `subprocess.call`,  it says you should not use PIPE with it